# Spring Quartz-scheduler : class not found Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I am using quartz-scheduler (version 2.3.0). It is giving the following Class not found exception when triggering the job. The class is there in the code. As a result, trigger state is marked to error. **The same code is deployed on other server and its running fine there without any exception.**. Not able to deduce why this is happening.

Exception :

```
Error retrieving job, setting trigger state to ERROR.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because a required class was not found:
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:quartz.properties")})
public class BillingInit implements Job {

  @Value("${cron.billing.init.cron.expression}")
  private String expression;

  @Autowired
  private BillingSchedulerService schedulerService;

  @Override
  public void execute(final JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
    schedulerService.scheduleBill();
  }

  @Bean(name = "billingInitCron")
  public JobDetailFactoryBean sampleJob() {
    return ConfigureQuartz.createJobDetail(this.getClass());
  }

  @Bean(name = "billingInitCronTrigger")
  public CronTriggerFactoryBean billingJobTrigger(
      @Qualifier("billingInitCron") final JobDetail jobDetail) {
    return ConfigureQuartz.createCronTrigger(jobDetail, expression);
  }
}
```

ConfigureQuartz.java

```
public static CronTriggerFactoryBean createCronTrigger(final JobDetail jobDetail,
      final String cronExpression) {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    factoryBean.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
    factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
    return factoryBean;
  }

public static JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail(
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") final Class jobClass) {
    JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
    // job has to be durable to be stored in DB:
    factoryBean.setDurability(true);
    return factoryBean;
  }
```

quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDs
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 25000
cron.billing.init.cron.expression = 0 0 0 * * ?
```

Comment: If possible can you please post full error details. any nested exceptions?

Comment: Classloader complains about some class is missing.
Is that class yours? Have you checked if this class is on the classpath ?
Maybe this class is not necessary, but some other class or configuration may be importing it.

Comment: @MebinJoe Yes, the class path is same. Same code is running fine when deployed on other server or on the same server again. Its like sometime scheduler-thread is getting the class and sometimes it's not.

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan No nested Exception.

Comment: Downgraded the version to 2.2.1 and everything is running fine. From when i upgraded the version, this issue is coming. Is this some version issue ?